# Cannot seem to get GLFW/OpenGL Depth Testing working

Tags: opengl, codeblocks, glfw

I cannot get Depth testing working with GLFW using codeblocks in any project, even using the default template provided by codeblocks when you start a new project, as below.

Any help is much appreciated as I know I must be doing something wrong but I haven't been able to find it.

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main()
{
int     width, height;
int     frame = 0;
bool    running = true;

glfwInit();

if( !glfwOpenWindow( 512, 512, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

glfwSetWindowTitle("GLFW Application");

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

while(running)
{
    frame++;

    glfwGetWindowSize( &width, &height );
    height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

    glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 65.0f, (GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height, 1.0f, 100.0f );

    // Draw some rotating garbage
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

    //glTranslatef( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    glRotatef(frame, 0.25f, 1.0f, 0.75f);
    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
      glColor3f(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
      glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, -4.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
      glVertex3f(3.0f, -2.0f, -4.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
      glVertex3f(-3.0f, -2.0f, -4.0f);
    glEnd();
    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f );
      glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
      glVertex3f(3.0f, -2.0f, -2.0f);
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
      glVertex3f(-3.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f);
    glEnd();
    glfwSwapBuffers();

    // exit if ESC was pressed or window was closed
    running = !glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED);
}

glfwTerminate();

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GLFW2 documentation](http://www.glfw.org/GLFWReference27.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> int glfwOpenWindow
>     (
>     int width, int height,
>     int redbits, int greenbits, int bluebits,
>     int alphabits,
>     int depthbits,
>     int stencilbits,
>     int mode
>     )
> ```
>
> *depthbits*: The number of bits to use for the depth buffer **(0 means no depth buffer)**.

And your code:

```
glfwOpenWindow( 512, 512, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW )
                                      ^ no depth bits
```

You can't (usefully) use the depth buffer without any depth bits.

Comment: Thanks, whats the recommended number of depth bits to use? 16 or 24?

Comment: @Whaill: The [GLFW3 docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html) say the default for `GLFW_DEPTH_BITS` is `24`, sounds reasonable to me.